# When we are using Kodein Aware framework, do we need to use Dagger as well?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Because both Kodein and Dagger are dependency injection frameworks, can we use only Dagger of Kodein or do we need to use both at the same time ?

Comment: Kodein and Dagger are dependencies framework. It not depend on each other. You can use only Kodein or Dagger. I recommend Dagger. It support by Google

Comment: I have never seen both Kodein and Dagger used at the same time in a project. Use one or the other.

Comment: ok thank you very much you solved my confusion